# Cant get the `/${i18n.locale}` work with v-bind:to directive

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

The header component immediately shuts down after I pass the locale global variable.

```html
<v-list>
                        <v-list-item
                                v-for="item in firesafety"
                                :to= "`/${i18n.locale}`"
                        >
                            <v-list-item-title>{{ item.name }}</v-list-item-title>
                        </v-list-item>
                    </v-list>
```

Comment: Please add more information, like what's the value - Can you put little more description if you get any error

Comment: Ive been trying to solve this for very long time, I managed to do it in a way : defining in the data  locale : `/${i18n.locale}`, but the bad thing is my buttons wont change the route after changing languange only when I refresh the page. Do you have any solution for this? I know I m giving way too less info I will try to provide more when I get back home if this is not enough. I have no idea why it acts like this, like I can define it in data but I cant call it in v-bind:to directive?